# How to include Laravel blade markdown within a component for mail?

Tags: laravel, routes, components, laravel-blade

I am trying to create a welcome email that has a button that links back to a user's profile within my Laravel project, but can't seem to get it to work. Here is my code:

```
@component('mail::message')
Thanks for signing up {{ $user->fn }}

@component('mail::button', ['url' => 'https://site.dev/users/{{ $user->id }}'])
Check out your profile!
@endcomponent

<br>

{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

When I try this the email sends, but it links to

```
https://site.dev/users/%3C?php%20echo%20e(%user-%3Eid);%20?%3E
```

How can I get this to work properly, reflected by a url like

```
https://site.dev/users/1
```

I have access to the user model traits but can't use the blade directives in this case, how else can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `.blade.php` file is rendered by Laravel, during this process the various Blade tags are converted into PHP to be executed. For example, `{{ $variable }}` is converted into `<?php e($variable); ?>`.

You do not need to use Blade tags when passing parameters to components, the parameters are passed in the same way you would pass parameters when calling a method in a controller or a model. Component parameters are defined using pure PHP, they do not involve Blade.

You can either concat the string like this:

```
@component('mail::button', ['url' => 'https://site.dev/users/' . $user->id])
    Check out your profile!
@endcomponent
```

or you can use curly braces in a double-quoted string:

```
@component('mail::button', ['url' => "https://site.dev/users/{$user->id}"])
    Check out your profile!
@endcomponent
```

or you could use the route helper (recommended):

```
@component('mail::button', ['url' => route('users.show', ['id' => $user->id])])
    Check out your profile!
@endcomponent
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick and effective solution! And for a little bit of background :)